# How to prove $\int_0^α (F(x+u)-F(x-u))du=(1/\pi)*\int (1-\cos(αt)/t^2)e^{(-itx)}Φ(t)dt$

Tags: probability

Suppose F is a probability distribution with characteristic function $Φ(t)$. Prove for all $\alpha>0$
$$\int_0^α (F(x+u)-F(x-u))du=\frac{1}{\pi}\int (\frac{1-\cos(αt)}{t^2})e^{(-itx)}Φ(t)dt$$
and,
$$\int_0^α \int_{-u}^{u} Φ(t)dt=2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\frac{(1-\cos(αx))}{x^2})F(dx)$$

I have reviewed the question [Integrate $2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1- \cos(tX)}{\pi t^2}~dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327070/integrate-2-int-0-infty-frac1-costx-pi-t2dt), but don't know how to plug this into the characteristic function integration

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I have added some notes I read.